# How can I keep this <li> tag on one line with tailwind/css

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am creating a horizontally scrolling menu with Tailwind.

Whenever I add enough elements to my `<ul>` list so that the elements extend past the right hand screen limit, my `<li>` tags seem to condense to be fixed width and cause the text within the `<li>` to break over multiple lines.

My code:

```
<ul class="p-2 mb-12 flex flex-nowrap overflow-scroll no-scrollbar">
    <li class="w-auto mx-1 p-3 px-8 border-gray-200 border rounded">Great</li>
    <li class="w-auto mx-1 p-3 px-8 border-gray-200 border rounded">Why am I not on one line?</li>
    <li class="w-auto mx-1 p-3 px-8 border-gray-200 border rounded">An element</li>

</ul>
```

[image]

If I remove the last element, so that the `<li>` elements remain within the screen boundary, everything looks fine...

```
<ul class="p-2 mb-12 flex flex-nowrap overflow-scroll no-scrollbar">
    <li class="w-auto mx-1 p-3 px-8 border-gray-200 border rounded">Great</li>
    <li class="w-auto mx-1 p-3 px-8 border-gray-200 border rounded">Why am I not on one line?</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

## Example

[play.tailwindcss.com/Y8LllBc93J](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Y8LllBc93J)

Comment: use `.w-fit` to fit the content

Comment: You explicitely set `flex-nowrap` ... that means the items itself don't wrap to a new line. That means your long text can't fit in one line without wrapping. So it is behaving exactly as you told it to.

Comment: Thanks, tried both suggestions, but still same issue as seen here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Y8LllBc93J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using `inline-block` instead of `flex`

```
<ul class="p-2 mb-12 whitespace-nowrap no-scrollbar overflow-x-scroll overflow-y-hidden">
    <li class="w-fit inline-block mx-1 p-3 px-8 border-gray-200 border rounded">Great</li>
    <li class="w-fit inline-block mx-1 p-3 px-8 border-gray-200 border rounded">Why am I not on one line?</li>
    <li class="w-fit inline-block mx-1 p-3 px-8 border-gray-200 border rounded">An element</li>
</ul>
```